# Change checkbox use 'Y' and 'N' instead of false and true

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using `mat-checkbox` angular material 7 and I want to change from true false to 'Y' and 'N' when to submit to backend.
I make like this but not working.

**HTML**

```
    <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)" class="form-horizontal row-border">
    <input matInput type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="userId"
                                        [ngModel]="selectedRow?.userId" [readonly]="selectedRow?.userId" id="userId"
                                        required>
    <input matInput type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="userName"
                                                [ngModel]="selectedRow?.userName" id="userName" required>
    <mat-checkbox type="text" name="blocked" [ngModel]="selectedRow?.blocked =='true'? 'Y':'N'"
                                                    id="blocked">{{selectedRow?.blocked}}</mat-checkbox>
<button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="primary"                                    ">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
 onSubmit(form: NgForm ){
    let value = this.selectedRow.blocked == true ? 'Y' : 'N';
    let data = form.value;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<mat-checkbox type="text" name="blocked" [(ngModel)]="selectedRow?.blocked" id="blocked">{{selectedRow?.blocked}}</mat-checkbox>
```

Instead to send an object, try to create a class and use it.
and in your method which send the data to server (as your "selectedRow"). Anyway, you can get the data from "selectedRow" object, instead of the form. In future, try to use [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

```
// create this class in a new file, outside of your component
    export class User {
      userId: number;
      userName: string;
      blocked: string;
    }

send() {
 let user = new User();
 user.userId = this.selectedRow.userId;     
 user.userName = this.selectedRow.userName;
 user.blocked = this.selectedRow.blocked == true ? 'Y' : 'N';
 // send user to api
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer...But how to combine with other post... like username and userId..I make like this.. `let data = form.value;`

Comment: put the code of your method in the post, please. You send directly "data" into server?